# Auto increment field not primary key on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im using a table to translate some IDs into others and and conversely.

```
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
| userId | visitorId                                     |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
|      1 | 015dc155838800b156253da37f0004078003b07000c48 |
|      2 | 015dbfdaeac50014c675298c726b04072003e06a00918 |
|      3 | 015dc26525ea00032eed79a4737d04092003a08a00978 |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I do so using this code

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    userId int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    visitorId varchar(255),
);
```

Simple, isn't it? I register each new visitor and it generates a unique ID (`userId`) for her. But how can it avoid inserting two times the same `visitorId`?

```
INSERT INTO Users (visitorId) VALUE ("1234"), ("1234"), ("1234")
+--------+-----------+
| userId | visitorId |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | 1234      |
|      2 | 1234      |
|      3 | 1234      |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Add a unique index on the column

Comment: Already tried. As the field `userId` will auto increment on its own, the set `(userId, visitorId)` wouldn't be unique

Comment: Only on the `visitorId` column

Comment: Then I won't be able to use auto increment on `userId`. I thoguth on using a big random number as a (userId)

Comment: Why do you think that is a problem?

Comment: Because then I ensure the _uniqueness_ of the `userId` and i don't need the `auto increment`. This way I can use the `visitorId` as the only primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153800/discussion-between-demil133-and-juergen-d).

Comment: If you want to use the visitorId as the unique identifier, you can make it the primary key and not use the userId column at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a unique to the column

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    userId int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    visitorId varchar(255) UNIQUE,
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You want a unique index or constraint on the `visitorId` column:

```
alter table users add constraint unq_users_visitorId unique (visitorId);
```

Comment: Your answer is also right. But since I want to create the table ready I accepted the one from @i-man